# How to force & by default subtitles FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, subtitle

Using code :  ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i input.sub.Eng.srt -i input.sub.bn.srt -map 0 -map 1 -map 2 -c copy -c:s mov_text -metadata:s:s:0 language=eng -metadata:s:s:1 language=ben -disposition:s:0 -outpur.mp4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the disposition flag has been added to FFmpeg, using the example you provided, you could set the subtitle track to display by default as follows:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i input1.srt -i input2.srt -c copy -c:s mov_text -metadata:s:s:0 language=eng -metadata:s:s:1 language=ben -disposition:s:1 default output-with-two-sub.mp4
```

You should use `-disposition:s:[1,2,3] default`, but You don't need to use -`disposition:s:0` for the first subtitle.
The format is `-disposition[:stream_specifier]` value.

If you need to remove a previously set disposition from a stream (for example, a stream is set to `default`, but you want to disable this), use the value `0`.

You can see the list of available disposition options and additional examples in the [ffmpeg documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html) by searching for "disposition".

Comment: Thanks for adding this answer, but AFAIK (I am still learning ffmpeg) it seems to only cover *default* streams... do you know how you can specifically *force* a subtitle stream (i.e. set forced=true) please? -- see screenshot for context/more info: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQoTj.png

Answer (score 1):

"Default & Forced" your subtitle stream X by using `-disposition:s:X default+forced`